# Hibernate setMaxresults with Detachedcriteria will not work

Tags: hibernate, hql

Here is my question I have a DetachedCriteria as follows where I need only one record with max ID need to fetch. But as of now I am fetched list of records as list and from there I am getting record with max Id using for loop.

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ContactList.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", id));

List contactList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

From contactList I am finding the recored with max Id with seperate loop.

My question is, Is there any way to add that restriction in DetachedCriteria itself.
I tried setMaxResults, but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ContactList.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userId", id)).setProjection(Projections.max("useId"));

List contactList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

Projection.max will retriev max value record from table in hibernate